# Multiple forms using filters django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-filter

I would like to display multiple forms with the same filter in a template.

Is it possible to do something like this ?

```
@register.filter
def formLightWithColor(phase,color):

    lightParameter = LightParameter.objects.filter(phase = phase).filter(color = color).all()
    all_params = None

    if lightParameter != None:
        for lights_params in lightParameter:
            all_params = ManageLight(instance=lights_params, prefix = lights_params.id).as_p()
        return all_params
    else:
        return None
```

And in the template :

```
{{ phase|formLightWithColor:color }}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it works :

```
@register.filter
def formLightWithColor(phase,color):
    lightParameter = LightParameter.objects.filter(phase=phase).filter(color=color).all()
    all_params = []
    if lightParameter != None:
        for lights_params in lightParameter:
            all_params.append(ManageLight(instance=lights_params, prefix=lights_params.id).as_p())
        return all_params
    else:
        return None
```

And in the template :

```
{% for light_form in phase|formLightWithColor:color %}
    {{ light_form }}
{% endfor %}
```